# Return 0 (instead of omitting the row) for a date/month without data

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find my below query

```
select concat(g.display_country_cd,to_char(cli.business_date,'YYYYMM')) year
,round(cli.amount/1000000) amount 
from cli_fact cli join geography g on cli.geo_skey=g.geo_skey 
where cli.region='ASIA' 
and to_char(cli.business_date,'MMYYYY') between '01'||'2013' and '06'||'2013'
```

how can i display 0 for a particular month if there are no records for any particular month using coalesce() or any other way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Join on a "months" table (possibly derived from a function) to synthesize missing rows. Coalesce can only be used *within* a row, but can't add a new row.

Comment: A dates table would be more useful than a months table.

Comment: @DanBracuk True, I'm just throwing out the concept, not the implementation xD

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try and let me know if any error occurs, code is not not tested but it should work -

```
with months(mon) as (
     select add_months(to_date( '01'||'2013', 'MMYYYY'), level - 1)
       from dual
    connect by add_months(to_date( '01'||'2013', 'MMYYYY'), level - 1) <= to_date( '06'||'2013', 'MMYYYY'))
select concat(g.display_country_cd,to_char(m.mon,'YYYYMM')) year,
       round((coalesce(cli.amount, 0))/1000000) amount  
  from months m
  left outer join cli_fact cli
       on to_char(m.mon,'MMYYYY') = to_char(cli.business_date,'MMYYYY') 
  left outer join geography g
       on cli.geo_skey=g.geo_skey;
```

Comment: Hi, this query is working fine for the months which have records but its still returning no records instead of 0 if there are no records

Comment: Oh.. that was a mistake, I took base table as `cli_fact` but it should be `months`, since data is missing from `cli_fact`, it should be outer joined to `months`. Modified the answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JOIN to be a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Good start, but incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query and let me know if it solves your issue.

```
WITH MONTHS AS 
(
       SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE( '01'||'2013', 'MMYYYY'), LEVEL - 1),'MMYYYY') MON     
       FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE( '01'||'2013', 'MMYYYY'), LEVEL - 1) <= TO_DATE( '06'||'2013', 'MMYYYY')
)
SELECT 
       CONCAT(G.DISPLAY_COUNTRY_CD,TO_CHAR(CLI.BUSINESS_DATE,'YYYYMM')) YEAR,
       ROUND((COALESCE(CLI.AMOUNT, 0))/1000000) AMOUNT 
  FROM CLI_FACT CLI, GEOGRAPHY G , MONTHS M 
       WHERE CLI.GEO_SKEY = G.GEO_SKEY
       AND M.MON = TO_CHAR(CLI.BUSINESS_DATE,'MMYYYY') (+)
       AND CLI.REGION='ASIA';
```